# REPLACE function Sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm working on SQLite database.
I've got something like :

> 07 22 2017 15:14:35.100577000

I want to transform it to :

> 07-22-2017 15:14:35.100577000

If i use replace with space to "-", i've :
07-22-2017-15:14:35.100577000

And i don't want this.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut the string up into a substring of the first 10 chars, do your replace on that bit only, and then concatenate on the remaining chars from the tail end:

```
SELECT replace(substr(x, 1, 10), ' ', '-')||substr(x,11)
```

Comment: select field replace(substr(field, 1, 10), ' ', '-')||substr(field,11) from DB;
returns me :
Error: near "(": syntax error

Don't understand why...

Comment: @Thibaud Because your code is not the same as in the answer.

Comment: The code is sound; go to sqliteonline.com and paste this in `SELECT replace(substr(hint, 1, 10), ' ', '-')||substr(hint,11) 
from demo` - it works just fine. I chose the HINT column out of their demo table. You have to correctly name your column in plae of `x`. Note if your column is called something that might be a reserved word (lots of people call their date columns "date" or something similarly unadvisable) you'll need to escape it ("double quotes" i think). Future tip, if this is the case: don't call your column anything that is a reserved word. Make it CreatedDate for example..